# How to add a placeholder attribute if "value" field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add a placeholder attribute (placeholder tag, not "defaultvalue" and similar approaches) if you have an text input field that has "value" property empty?

I have seen many similar questions here, but most of them use defaultvalue. I need placeholder tags and additionally I can't influence HTML output at all.

This is the given HTML output example:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="textbox" id="edit-textbox">
```

Comment: @RPM It would be too simple, wouldn't it? :) I wrote that I can't influence HTML output. This is the code I have and I have to add the placeholder attribute with jQuery

Comment: It doesn't influence HTML output at all (excepting by adding the placeholder, which is what you need, isn't it??)!
But remember that it's for HTML 5!

Comment: We didn't understand each other. I have this code written in the question. I can't do anything with it but manipulate it with jquery. Your solution from the fiddle suggests that I just edit the HTML code, which I can't without js.

Comment: Just note that I'm not the person who posted it to the fiddle. I think  I got what you mean now. I'll edit my answer bellow.

Comment: @take2: As you could have found by searching, there is a "HTML5" `placeholder` attribute/property (which you can also set via JS) and there's a bunch of plugins/snippets for browsers which don't support it. So where are you stuck effectively?

Comment: @Bergi Obviously, as demonstrated here, there are much simpler approaches for something like this, then loading a plugin for adding a few words. Only a small percentage of my visitors have browsers that don't support placeholder attribute, so I don't have to bother with browser support too much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest any one of the following approaches:

```
$('input:text').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = 'placeholdertext';
            /* or:
            el.placeholder = $('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text();
            */
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo using `el.placeholder = 'placeholdertext'`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/).

[JS Fiddle demo using `el.placeholder = $('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/1/).

Or you could use an array to store the various placeholders:

```
var placeholders = ['Email address', 'favourite color'];

$('input:text').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = placeholders[i];
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/2/).

To specify a particular placeholder for a particular element:

```
var placeholders = {
    'one' : 'Email address',
    'two' : 'Favourite color'
};

$('input:text').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = placeholders[el.id];
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/3/).

Added a catch/fall-back in the event that an entry doesn't exist in the placeholders object for a particular `input`:

```
var placeholders = {
    'oe' : 'Email address', // <-- deliberate typo over there
    'two' : 'Favourite color'
};

$('input:text').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = placeholders[el.id] || '';
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/4/).

Comment: I have tried with the both suggestions, but it didn't work...you can check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/U2YZx

Comment: You need to have an actual label element to work with in that code. You don't have one, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! One questions about this code though - how do you reference which text box should be affected, i. e. how can I target the exact input box (with #textbox in this case)?

Comment: Do you want to know how to specify a placeholder-message for a particular element?

Comment: Yes. I have 2-3 text boxes on this page, so I want to target only this one, the others don't need the placeholder.

Comment: Okay, you're going to have to supply some form of demo for me to work with. Show *which* `input` you want to have a particular `placeholder`, and which you don't want to have a (particular) placeholder.

Comment: Here you can see HTML code. It's nothing different, there are two boxes that are the same, but only one needs the placeholder: http://jsfiddle.net/pvDEF/

Comment: @DavidThomas nice explanation and i have tried it and although it works on firefox and chrome it failed in IE8 . can you suggest me anyother solution may be light weight js that dynamically works in all browser.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using HTML5 (and you should) there's a native placeholder attribute.

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="My placeholder!" name="textbox" id="edit-textbox">
```

**Edit**

As you said you can't edit the HTML and have to use JS, this may help.

$('#edit-textbox').attr('placeholder', 'My placeholder!');

Once again, this is for HTML 5.

Comment: This one also works, thanks! David was the first one though, so I have accepted his answer.

Comment: Ok! Just note that our answers are absolutely different and lead to different things.

Your question was: "How to add a placeholder attribute" and setting a value attribute (as in his answer) is absolutely not the same as it.

Comment: I have checked his code with firebug, and placeholder text is displayed as a placeholder attribute, so it would be the answer to my question.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, you're absolutely right!
I was mislead by the use of 'if' in his code and that's why I thought he was using the value attribute. If you're setting the right attribute (placeholder) you don't need an if statement to check if the value is empty as the meaning of the placeholder attribute is to set a value IF the value is empty.

Comment: No problem ;) Honestly, I really don't know such details, maybe you should suggest it to David Thomas, you guys can discuss it better.

Comment: I don't need to, I can just correct his code above, which I'll do right now. Be sure to use the correct one, ok??
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

  $('#edit-textbox').attr('placeholder','Your placeholder text');

})(jQuery);
```