# Adding 'placeholder' text to an element using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

-

There are a few posts on this already ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993130/how-to-add-a-placeholder-attribute-if-value-field-is-empty)) but they're not really adaptable to this situation.

I have a shortcode that dynamically generates text content based on a custom field in my CRM, this is used to display a users serial number for their software, shown below:

[image: Serial Number Field]

The direct parent container for the serial number is `#copyTarget2`.

When the container is empty it is still rendered on the page but with no content, shown here:

[image: Empty Serial Number Container]

I need to populate the empty container with 'placeholder' text, but not the kind that you can type over, just so that there is text visible that just reads - '**No active serial number**.'

Lastly, when the field is populated, the placeholder text needs to be hidden, it doesn't really matter how it's hidden so long as it's not visible and doesn't affect the text generated by the shortcode.

---

I also tried to adapt this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/

From:

```
$('input:text').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = 'placeholdertext';
            /* or:
            el.placeholder = $('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text();
            */
        }
    });
```

To:

```
jQuery('#copyTarget2').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = 'No valid serial number.';
            /* or:
            el.placeholder = $('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text();
            */
        }
    });
```

CSS and HTML are like second languages to me but I'm new to JS so I can modify code a little but I can't write it (yet), I'm wondering what the best JS solution would be to achieve this and why?

Comment: with jQuery you can do `$('#id').attr('placeholder', 'value')` - https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I don't get your point ?.But you need a function like `placeholder ` in the span element not the input tag.right?

Comment: It would help if you put the HTML markup in your post so we know what you are working with.

Comment: @epascarello HTML: `<span id="copyTarget2"><strong>[memb_contact fields="_AFXSerial"]</strong></span>`

Comment: Well that your placeholder code will not work since you do not have an input, you would need to use the CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a effect like `placeholder` in the span element not the input tag .Try with some css .see the below snippet .And add the attribute using [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7t6uGq-rTAhUBOY8KHYP-CX4QFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg) of `jquery` function

see the [`CSS content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

```js
jQuery('#copyTarget2').each(
  function(i, el) {
    if (!$(el).text() || $(el).text().trim() == '') {
      $(el).attr('placeholder', 'No valid serial number.')
      /* or:
      el.placeholder = $('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text();
      */
    }
  });
```

```css
span:empty:before {
  font-size: 12;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
span{
position:absolute;/*or fix as your wish with respect to parent element*/
width:200px;/*or fix as your wish with respect to parent element*/
height:50px;/*or fix as your wish with respect to parent element*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="copyTarget2"></span>
```

Comment: spans do not have values... And there is really no need for JavaScript, just the CSS and the attribute

Comment: @epascarello *`And there is really no need for JavaScript`* then how to validate the element is empty ?

Comment: @prasad hi thanks, I tried this but it didn't seem to render anything on the page accept for adding a 1px grey border (as specified in the CSS you provided) to many of the page's elements

Comment: border not necessary `content:attr()` and `color` is main .

Comment: @prasad it's odd it just doesn't seem to display anything on the front end and the #copyTarget2 box is still showing as in the question (i.e 0x0 in size)

Comment: @JackVanstone *`it just doesn't seem to display anything`* .yes .Because the size ` 0x0` is not visible .change the `width` and `height` of the span.see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using :empty and :before with attribute to set the placeholder when it is empty.

```css
[data-placeholder]:empty:before {
  color: #AAA;
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

```html
<span data-placeholder="My placeholder"></span>
<br/>
<span data-placeholder="My placeholder">I have text</span>
```